# ¿Para que sirve y como se limpia el buffer?

Tags: c++

Soy iniciado en programacion y estoy estudiando arrays y punteros pero me he topado con el tema del buffer y quisiera despejar dos dudas:

- ¿Para que sirve limpiar el buffer?
- ¿Como se limpia el buffer?

He visto que se suele usar la funcion `cin.ignore()` pero la verdad no entiendo como se usa, de ser posible ponganme unos ejemplos para saber como y cuando se usa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supones que tienes una aplicación que, a medida que pasan las cosas va haciendo preguntas al usuario...

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Espere..." << std::endl;
    // aqui hace una (quiza larga) operacion y de repente pregunta
    std::cout << "Elija una opcion? [A,B,C]" << std::endl;    
    std::cin >> opcion;
    // y sigue con la operacion en base a la opcion 
}
```

En un caso así, seria importante limpiar el buffer de entrada, pues durante la espera, el usuario pudo tocar el teclado sin la intención, y este toque accidental ha quedado en el buffer hasta tanto sea leída la entrada standard (cin).

Es una decision de diseño, cuando quieres estar (algo mas) seguro que es una decision consiente del usuario y por ello no aceptas los datos del buffer.

Entonces antes de `cin >> opcion` pones `cin.ignore(N)`, para descartar N bytes del buffer de entrada, forzadamente.

Por ultimo, no estoy seguro de que exista una solución portable a todas las plataformas, esta es la base. Hay [otras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257182/2573335) opciones mas del estilo c++.

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```