# Cargar dimensión de matriz vía teclado

Tags: c++, matrices

¿Cómo hago para dimensionar una matriz con los datos que carga el usuario en C++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int a,b,fila=0,columna=0;
    system ("color F3");
    cout << "\t\t\t PROGRAMA DE MATRIZ EJ 1 C++" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese el valor de filas que quiere que tenga la matriz: "; cin >> fila;
    cout << "Ingrese el valor de columnas que quiere que tenga la matriz: "; cin >> columna;
    std::vector<int>Matriz(fila,columna);

    cout << "Ingrese el valor de los elementos de la matriz: " << endl;
    for(a = 0; a < fila ; a++)
    { 
        for (b = 0; b < columna ; a++)
            cin >> matriz[a][b];       
    }

    for(a = 0; a < fila ; a++)
    { 
        for (b = 0; b < columna ; b++)
            cout << matriz[a][b] << endl; 
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

El error que tira es el siguiente

```
error: invalid types 'int[int]'
```

Comment: y el problema es?

Comment: Si quieres usar arreglos dinamicos usa punteros, ojo el system("pause") despues del return no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 3):

#### Problema.

Completo desconocimiento de la [librería estándar de plantillas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) (STL).

#### Solución.

Lee la documentación de la clase [`std::vector`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

#### Descripción del problema, paso a paso.

La clase `std::vector` es un contenedor de la librería estándar de plantillas que permite almacenar datos de manera anexa en memoria y acceder a los elementos almacenados mediante el operador corchetes (`[` y `]`), podría considerarse como una versión ampliada y segura del arreglo tradicional.

**Constructor**.

El `std::vector` [dispone de ocho constructores distintos](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) de los que voy a mencionar sólo los tres más relevantes para esta pregunta:

1. `vector()`

   Construye un vector vacío (delega en el constructor que recibe un
   [`allocator`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator)).
2. `vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());`

   Construye un vector con `count` elementos todos ellos inicializados al valor `value`, se usará el alojador `alloc` para alojar los datos.
3. `explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`

   Construye un vector con `count` elementos, todos los elementos serán alojados por el alojador `alloc` y serán inicializados con el valor por defecto del tipo alojado.

El constructor que has usado en tu caso:

```
std::vector<int>Matriz(fila,columna);
```

Es el segundo, así que al contrario de lo que (parece que) crees, no estás creando una Matriz de Y `fila`s por X `columna`s si no un vector de `fila` elementos inicializados al valor `columna`

**Operador corchetes**.

El operador corchetes de `std::vector` ([`std::vector::operator []`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)) dispone de dos sobrecargas, una de sólo lectura y otra de lectura-escritura:

- `reference operator[]( size_type pos );`
- `const_reference operator[]( size_type pos ) const;`

Devuelve en cada caso una referencia al dato almacenado (`std::vector::reference` o `std::vector::const_reference`), en tu caso:

```
cin >> matriz[a][b];
```

Suponiendo que `matriz` (con m minúscula) sea lo mismo<sup>1</sup> que lo que `Matriz` (con M mayúscula) que has declarado unas líneas atrás, al usar el primer operador corchete `[a]` estás obteniendo una referencia al dato almacenado en `matriz`, que viendo la declaración sabemos que es `int`. Sobre el `int` obtenido entonces usas otro operador corchetes `[b]` y es ahí cuando obtienes el error que mencionas:

> ```
>  error: invalid types 'int[int]'
> ```

Ya que intentas indexar con corchetes un tipo no indexable (`int`).

**Propuesta**.

Para conseguir lo que (parece que) quieres en el código que has mostrado, deberás usar un vector de vectores, para que sea más cómodo de usar te aconsejo definir un [alias](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
using Matriz = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
```

Con ello, tu código podría quedar así:

```
int main () {
    std::size_t fila=0u,columna=0u;

    std::cout << "\t\t\t PROGRAMA DE MATRIZ EJ 1 C++\n\n";
    std::cout << "Ingrese el valor de filas que quiere que tenga la matriz: ";
    std::cin >> fila;

    std::cout << "Ingrese el valor de columnas que quiere que tenga la matriz: ";
    std::cin >> columna;

    using Matriz = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
    // Utilizamos el segundo y tercer constructor de std::vector
    Matriz matriz = { fila, std::vector<int>(columna) };

    std::cout << "Ingrese el valor de los elementos de la matriz: \n";
    for(int a = 0; a < fila ; a++)
    { 
        for (int b = 0; b < columna ; a++)
            std::cin >> matriz[a][b];       
    }

    for(int a = 0; a < fila ; a++)
    { 
        for (int b = 0; b < columna ; b++)
            std::cout << matriz[a][b] << '\n'; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Date cuenta que he eliminado la línea `using namespace std`, consulta [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%c3%a9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%c3%a1ctica) para saber por qué. También he eliminado los `std::endl`, consulta [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47839/c-instrucci%c3%b3n-endl) para saber por qué. También he cambiado el tipo de `fila` y `columna` a [`std::size_t`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) ya que es el tipo que esperan los constructores de `std::vector` para las partes en que se usen tamaños y he eliminado las variables `a` y `b` que pueden (y deben) crearse en los bucles en que son usadas (no antes), respecto a los bucles, una posible mejora sería usar los bucles de rango (ya que trabajamos con contenedores):

```
    std::cout << "Ingrese el valor de los elementos de la matriz: \n";
    for(auto &fila : matriz)
    { 
        for (auto &valor : fila)
            std::cin >> valor;
    }

    for(auto &fila : matriz)
    { 
        for (auto &valor : fila)
            std::cout << valor << '\n'; 
    }
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Sorpresa: No lo es. En C++ los nombres de identificadores son sensibles a mayúsculas/minúsculas.

Comment: +1, me dio mucha gracias la parte de `Problema` y `Solucion`

Answer (score 1):

En el caso que expones, **no hace falta** siquiera que trabajes con matrices de verdad.

Para usar un `::std::vector< int >`, basta con que, al indicar su tamaño, calcules `filas * columnas`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  int a,fila,columna;
  system ("color F3");
  cout << "\t\t\t PROGRAMA DE MATRIZ EJ 1 C++" << endl << endl;
  cout << "Ingrese el valor de filas que quiere que tenga la matriz: "; cin >> fila;
  cout << "Ingrese el valor de columnas que quiere que tenga la matriz: "; cin >> columna;
  vector<int> Matriz(fila*columna);

  cout << "Ingrese el valor de los elementos de la matriz: " << endl;

  for(a = 0; a < fila*columna ; a++)
    cin >> Matriz[a];      

  cout << "Matriz introducida:\n";

  for(a = 0; a < fila*columna ; a++ )
    cout << Matriz[a] << endl; 

  system ("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Como verás, he eliminado la variable `b`, que ya no hace falta. Y he dejado sin inicializar `filas` y `columnas`, ya que de todos modos los vamos a pedir al usuario.

Podíamos haber usado la `b` para almacenar el resultado de `filas * columnas`, y no tener que estar repitiéndolo en cada bucle; una simple modificación que puedes hacerle.

Comment: Que pasa si forzosamente necesita un arreglo de 2 dimensiones, ejemplo si el solamente quiere consultar los datos de la segundo fila, seria bueno que explicaras como puede simular este mecanismo en una matriz de una sola dimension.