# Algo no funciona en mi implementación de listas abiertas

Tags: c++, lista

Mi main.cpp contiene lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct nodo {
    int dato;
    nodo* siguiente = NULL;
};

typedef nodo* lista;

void agregar(int nuevoDato, lista unaLista) {
    if (unaLista == NULL) {
        unaLista = new nodo;
        unaLista -> dato = nuevoDato;
        cout << "Nodo agregado (" << unaLista -> dato << ")" << endl;
    } else {
        agregar(nuevoDato, unaLista -> siguiente);
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void mostrar(lista unaLista) {
    cout << "Lista:" << endl;
    if (unaLista == NULL) {
        cout << "-" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << unaLista -> dato << endl;
        mostrar(unaLista -> siguiente);
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    lista laLista;
    agregar(7, laLista);
    agregar(4, laLista);
    mostrar(laLista);
}
```

Al compilarlo y correrlo, espero esto en consola:

```
Nodo agregado (7)
Nodo agregado (4)

Lista:
7
4
-

Process returned 0 [...]
```

Sin embargo, obtengo esto:

```
Nodo agregado (7)
Nodo agregado (4)

Lista:
-

Process returned 0 [...]
```

Mi pregunta es por qué obtengo una lista vacía si agregué nodos previamente. ¿El problema es `agregar()`, `mostrar()`, o se trata de algo más?

Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Los nodos no son listas.

He visto en StackOverflow en Español varias veces esta confusión, y me resulta muy curioso que tantos usuarios cometan ese error.

En el código que has facilitado creas un alias de puntero a nodo (`nodo*`) y dices que es una lista (`lista`), eso es tan erróneo como decir que un escalón es una escalera, sinceramente ¿Te parecen lo mismo?:

[image]
[image]

#### Los errores de tu código.

El punto anterior es importante porque ese alias incorrecto que has usado es lo que está provocando tu error, en concreto está en tu función `agregar` en que pasas un puntero a nodo (`lista`) **por copia**, dado que `agregar` recibe una copia es ésta la que se modifica dejando el original (`laLista` de la función `main`) sin modificar. Por ese motivo, cuando le pasas `laLista` a la función `mostrar` (también por copia) actúa como si la lista no hubiera recibido elementos, que es de hecho lo que ha sucedido. Tal vez sin el alias te habrías dado cuenta sin ayuda, pero ese alias oculta el tipo puntero haciendo el error menos evidente.

Además no liberas la memoria dinámica solicitada, tu función `main` no tiene valor de retorno, generalmente no se aconseja usar `using namespace std;` (consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%C3%A9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica) para saber por qué) y hay que usar `std::endl` con cuidado (consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47839/c-instrucci%C3%B3n-endl) para saber por qué).

#### Solución.

Si quieres seguir con tu diseño actual (que al igual que [akko](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/120933/2742) no te lo aconsejo), deberás cambiar la firma de `agregar` y `mostrar` para recibir referencias en lugar de copias:

```
//        Referencia a lista ---> v
void agregar(int nuevoDato, lista &unaLista) {
//                  vvvvvvv <--- literal de puntero nulo, evita usar la macro NULL
    if (unaLista == nullptr) {
//                     vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--- inicializacion uniforme de datos simples
        unaLista = new nodo{nuevoDato};
        std::cout << "Nodo agregado (" << unaLista -> dato << ")\n";
//      ^^^^^ <--- espacio de nombres explicito               ^^^^^
//                                    evitamos el uso de endl --/
    } else {
        agregar(nuevoDato, unaLista -> siguiente);
    }
    std::cout << '\n'; // <-- evitamos el uso de endl
//  ^^^^^ <--- espacio de nombres explicito
}

//                 v <--- Referencia a lista
void mostrar(lista &unaLista) {
// Evitando la recursividad innecesaria
    for (auto nodo = unaLista; nodo; nodo = nodo -> siguiente)
        std::cout << nodo -> dato << '\n'; // <-- evitamos el uso de endl
//      ^^^^^ <--- espacio de nombres explicito
    std::cout << "-\n"; // <-- evitamos el uso de endl
//  ^^^^^ <--- espacio de nombres explicito
}
```

#### Propuesta.

Tal y como propone [akko](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/120933/2742) crea un objeto `lista`:

```
struct lista
{
    void agregar(int nuevoDato) {
        agregar(nuevoDato, raiz);
    }

    void mostrar() {
        for (auto nodo = raiz; nodo; nodo = nodo -> siguiente)
            std::cout << nodo -> dato << '\n';
        std::cout << "-\n";
    }

    ~lista() {
        do
        {
            auto temp = raiz -> siguiente;
            delete raiz;
            raiz = temp;
        } while (raiz);
    }

private:

    // nodo privado, no requerimos el nodo fuera de la lista.
    struct nodo {
        int dato;
        nodo* siguiente = nullptr;
    };

    //     Referencia a puntero ---> vv
    void agregar(int nuevoDato, nodo *&unaLista) {
        if (unaLista == nullptr) {
            unaLista = new nodo{nuevoDato};
        } else {
            agregar(nuevoDato, unaLista -> siguiente);
        }
    }

    // Raiz de la lista.
    nodo *raiz = nullptr;
};
```

Este objeto `lista` sigue los principios de [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)) al prohibir el acceso a los datos privados de la lista (el tipo `nodo` y todos los nodos almacenados) y libera la memoria al finalizar su ciclo de vida evitando fugas de memoria.

Comment: Más allá de agradecerte por tanta calidad en tu respuesta, quiero aclarar que la confusión entre listas y nodos la pesqué de [acá](http://c.conclase.net/edd/index.php?cap=001#1_2) (probablemente le haya pasado lo mismo a muchos más).

Comment: Gracias por la información @tamura he visto el tutorial de esa página sobre listas simplemente enlazadas y tiene varios fallos, no sólo el que mencionamos, intentaré contactar con el autor.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo crear dos clases (Una struct es una clase con todos sus elementos public ): Una clase para la lista, la cual contenga sus métodos como agregar y eliminar de la lista; y una clase que defina el nodo.

```
#ifndef NODO_H
#define NODO_H

class Nodo{
private:
    int numero;
    Nodo* Siguiente;
public:
    Nodo(int n): numero{n}, Siguiente{NULL} {}
    friend class Lista;
};

#endif
```

Lista.h

```
class Lista{
private:
    int contador = 0;
    Nodo* Cabeza;
    Nodo* Cola;
    Nodo* Temporal;
public:
    Lista(): Actual{NULL}, Cabeza{NULL}, Temporal{NULL} {}
    bool ListaVacia(){
        return(Cabeza == NULL);
    }
    void AgregarCola(int n){
        Actual = new Nodo(n);
        // if ListaVacia == true
        //     Cabeza = Actual
        //     Cola = Actual
        //     Temporal = Actual
        // else
        //     Recorre la lista hasta el final y agrega el elemento
        // contador++
    }
}
```

Te recomiendo ver este video para entender mejor como representar la idea de la lista en código.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5wJkJJpKtM

Comment: Me parece una buena sugerencia y te lo agradezco :) ... aunque sigo sin saber por qué mi solución no funciona, que es mi pregunta.