# Cómo insertar un objeto a una lista ligada?

Tags: c++, lista

en la escuela estamos creando un juego, a nivel nada gráfico, para la nueva actividad me era necesario insertar un objeto en una clase, la cual crea nodos y los enlaza haciendo una lista ligada, mi problema es que no entiendo cómo insertar este objeto dentro de la lista, tengo que reservar memoria al objeto con **new**.

En resumen, necesito ayuda para crear diversas civilizaciones, la lista guarda civilizaciones y las civilizaciones guardan aldeanos con sus atributos.
Gracias por la ayuda!

Esta es la clase de la lista ligada(lista.h):

```
#ifndef LISTA_H
#define LISTA_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Nodo
{
    T dato;
    Nodo<T> *sig;

public:
    Nodo(const T &d, Nodo<T> *s = nullptr)//Tipo - Nombre,Direccion(&)
    {
        dato = d;
        sig = s;
    }

    template <class>
    friend class Lista;
};

template <class T>
class Lista
{
    Nodo<T> *raiz;
public:
    Lista();
    ~Lista();
    void insertarIn(const T &d);
    void insertarFi(const T &d);
    void insertarPo(const T &d, int pos);

    void eliminarI();
    void eliminarF();

    int tamano();

    T &operator [](int pos);
};

template <class T>
Lista<T>::Lista()
{
    //Raiz apunta a vacio
    raiz = nullptr;
}

template<class T>
Lista<T>::~Lista()
{
    Nodo<T> *temp = raiz;
    while(temp != nullptr){
        raiz = raiz->sig;
        delete temp;
        temp = raiz;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Lista<T>::insertarIn(const T &d)
{
    if (raiz==nullptr) {
        //Crea un nuevo nodo si raiz apunta a vacio y apunta raiz a ese nodo
        Nodo<T> *nuevo = new Nodo<T>(d);
        raiz = nuevo;
    } else {
        //Crea nodo y apunta la raiz a ese nuevo nodo enlazado a el anterior
        Nodo<T> *nuevo = new Nodo<T>(d);
        nuevo->sig = raiz;
        raiz = nuevo;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Lista<T>::insertarFi(const T &d)
{
    if (raiz==nullptr) {
        //Crea un nuevo nodo si raiz apunta a vacio y apunta raiz a ese nodo
        Nodo<T> *nuevo = new Nodo<T>(d);
        raiz = nuevo;
    } else {
        //Crea nodo y apunta la raiz a ese nuevo nodo enlazado a el anterior
        Nodo<T> *temp = raiz;

        while (temp->sig != nullptr) {//Busca una dirección nula para agregar al final
            temp = temp->sig;//Salto a siguiente nodo
        }

        Nodo<T> *nuevo = new Nodo<T>(d);//Nodo a agregar
        temp->sig = nuevo;//Temp apunta al nuevo nodo
    }
}

template<class T>
void Lista<T>::insertarPo(const T &d, int pos)
{
    if (pos < 0) {
        //Pos invalida
    }else{
        Nodo<T> *temp = raiz;
        int cont = 0;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            if (cont++ == pos) {
                Nodo<T> *nuevo = new Nodo<T>(d);
                nuevo -> sig = temp->sig;
                temp->sig=nuevo;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->sig;
        }
    }
}

template<class T>
void Lista<T>::eliminarI()
{
    if (raiz==nullptr) {
        throw out_of_range ("Lista vacia");
    }else{
        Nodo<T> *temp = raiz;
        raiz = raiz->sig;
        delete temp;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Lista<T>::eliminarF()
{
    if(raiz == nullptr){
        throw out_of_range("Lista vacia, eliminarf");
    }else if (raiz->sig==nullptr) {
        delete raiz;
        raiz = nullptr;
        //eliminarI();
    }else{
        Nodo<T> *temp = raiz;
        while (temp->sig->sig != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->sig;
        }
        delete temp->sig;
        temp->sig = nullptr;
    }
}

template<class T>
int Lista<T>::tamano()
{
    Nodo<T> *temp = raiz;
    int cont = 0;
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        cont++;
        temp = temp->sig;
    }
    return cont;
}

template<class T>
T &Lista<T>::operator [](int pos)
{
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= tamano()) {
        throw out_of_range("Posicion invalida");
    } else {
        Nodo<T> *temp = raiz;
        int cont = 0;

        while (temp != nullptr) {
            if (cont == pos) {
                return temp->dato;
            }
            temp = temp->sig;
            cont ++;
        }
    }
}
#endif // LISTA_H
```

El proyecto consta de una clase aldeanos, crea aldeanos con atributos tales como nombre, edad, genero. Y una clase **civilización** la cual crea arrays para guardar ahí los aldeanos.

Con la clase **Lista** quiero crear listas de la clase **civilización** para así poder crear múltiples civilizaciones, el profesor nos dio el siguiente ejemplo de como podríamos y deberíamos usarlo:

```
void agregarCiv(Lista<Civilizacion*> &Lista){
            //definicion de variables
            string nombre;
            Civilizacion *c = new Civilizacion(); 
            cout << "-Nombre de la civilizacion: ";
            getline(cin, nombre);
            c->setNombreC(nombre);
            //insertar en la lista el objeto *c
            list.insertarIn(c);
        }
```

**Mi problema** es esta parte de aquí `Civilizacion *c = new Civilizacion();`, cree un menú aparte según dicta la actividad para hacer eso:

```
#include "menuc.h"
#include "menu.h"
#include "civilizacion.h"
#include "aldeano.h"
#include "lista.h"

MenuC::MenuC()
{
    string op;
    //Aldeano a;///Para el aldeano
    //Civilizacion<Aldeano> arr;///Para el arreglo
    Lista<Civilizacion> list;

    while (true) {
        //Opciones del menu
        cout << "1) Agregar civilizacion a la lista simplemente ligada" << endl;
        cout << "2) Buscar civilizacion" << endl;
        cout << "3) Eliminar civilizacion" << endl;
        cout << "4) Mostrar civilizaciones";
        cout << "Opcion: "; getline(cin, op);
        system("cls");
**AQUI**
        if (op=="1") {
            /* Agregar civilizacion
             * Creara un objeto apuntador de la clase "civilizacion"
             */

            Civilizacion<Aldeano> *c = new Civilizacion<Aldeano>;
            c->setNombreC("Test");
            list.insertarIn(c);


        }else if(op=="2"){
            /*
             * Buscar civilizacion
             * pedira el nombre de una civilizacíon, si la civilizacion no
             * existe, mostrar un mensaje. Si existe la civilizacion,
             * mostrar el menu de la actividad 01
             */
        }else if (op=="3") {
            /*Eliminar civilizacion
             * Pedira el nombre de la civilizacion y eliminara el nodo de la lista
             * simplemente ligada que corresponda a la civilizacion con ese nombre
             */
        }else if (op=="4") {
            /*Mostrar civilizaciones
             * Muestra en pantalla el nombre de la civilizacion y su población
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Donde dice **AQUI** es lo que intento para que funcione pero no funciona y QT me manda error:

**Error 1**
Linea 12: `Lista<Civilizacion> list;`

Error: *type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template class Lista'*

**Error 2**
Linea 30 : `list.insertarIn(c);`

Error: *request for member 'insertIn' in 'list', wich is of non-class type 'int'*

Por último anexo la clase civilización y el enlace a un repositorio de github donde están todas las clases:

**civilización.h**

```
#ifndef CIVILIZACION_H
#define CIVILIZACION_H

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Civilizacion
{
private:
    T *arreglo;
    int indice;
    int tam;
    const static int MAX = 5;
    ///Nombre por defecto de la civ.
    string nombreC = "SIN NOMBRE";
public:
    Civilizacion();
    ~Civilizacion();
    string getNombreC();
    void setNombreC(string s);
    void agregarA(const T &dato);
    int linearFindData(const T &name);
    void eliminarA(int pos);
    int poblacionT();
    int tamanio();
    bool isEmpty();

    T &operator[](int posicion);

};

template <class T>
Civilizacion<T>::Civilizacion()
{
    arreglo = new T[MAX];
    indice = 0;
    tam = MAX;
}

template <class T>
Civilizacion<T>::~Civilizacion()
{
    delete[]arreglo;
}

template<class T>
string Civilizacion<T>::getNombreC()
{
    return nombreC;
}

template<class T>
void Civilizacion<T>::setNombreC(string s)
{
    nombreC = s;
}

template<class T>
void Civilizacion<T>::agregarA(const T &dato)
{
    if(indice < tam){
        ///Si el indice es menor al tam total se agrega el aldeano
        arreglo[indice++] = dato;
        cout << endl << "-=ALDEANO AGREGADO=-" << endl << endl;
    }else{
        ///Si no se aumenta el tam y se crea un nuevo arreglo y se agrega el     aldeano
        T *nuevo = new T[tam+5];
        for (int i = 0; i < indice; ++i) {
            nuevo[i]=arreglo[i];
        }
        delete []arreglo;
        arreglo = nuevo;
        arreglo[indice++] = dato;
        tam = tam + 5;
        cout << endl << "-=ALDEANO AGREGADO=-" << endl << endl;
    }
}

template <class T>
int Civilizacion<T>::linearFindData(const T& name) {
    ///Busca el nombre del aldeano si lo encuentra regresa su posicion
    int i(0);
    while( i <= indice){
        if(arreglo[i] == name){
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    ///Si no lo encuentra regresa -1 (Inexistente)
    return -1;
    }


template<class T>
void Civilizacion<T>::eliminarA(int pos)
{
    if (pos >= indice or pos < 0) {
        ///Revisa si hay espacio para eliminar(Obsoleto por 'isEmpty()')
        cout << "-=POSICION INVALIDA=-";
    }
    for (int i = pos; i < indice - 1; ++i) {
        ///Recorre el arreglo para sobreescribir la posicion
        arreglo[i] = arreglo[i+1];
    }
    ///Reduce el indice diciendo que hay un aldeano menos
    indice--;
}

template<class T>
int Civilizacion<T>::poblacionT()
{
    return indice;
}

template<class T>
int Civilizacion<T>::tamanio()
{
    return tam;
}

template<class T>
bool Civilizacion<T>::isEmpty()
{
    ///Si el indice es igual a '0' no hay nada en el arreglo
    return indice == 0;
}

template<class T>
T &Civilizacion<T>::operator[](int posicion)
{
    ///Operador sobrecargado para poder imprimir el arreglo tipo T
    if (posicion < 0 or posicion >= indice){
        cout << "-=POSICION INVALIDA=-";
    }
    return arreglo[posicion];
}

#endif // CIVILIZACION_H
```

**ENLACE REPO**
[GitHub](https://github.com/ChikenGamer/GameID)

Comment: El simple hecho de ver `template` me hace pensar que no es código [tag:c], etiqueta eliminada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `Civilizacion` es una clase plantilla.

> Error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template class Lista'

Estás usando `Civilizacion` como clase normal pero es una clase plantilla. Cada instancia de la plantilla `Civilizacion` es un tipo distinto, así que no puedes tener una lista de objetos `Civilizacion`, puedes sin embargo tener una lista de objetos `Civilizacion<int>` o `Civilizacion<Aldeano>` o `Civilizacion<tipo_de_datos>`.

#### Almacenas objetos, insertas punteros a dichos objetos.

> Error: request for member 'insertIn' in 'list', wich is of non-class type 'int'

Tus funciones `Lista::insertar*` reciben como parámetro `const T &`, es decir: referencia constante al tipo almacenado. Suponiendo que tengas una lista de `Civilizacion<Aldeano>` la instancia de dichas funciones de tu clase plantilla sería:

```
void insertarIn(const Civilizacion<Aldeano> &d);
void insertarFi(const Civilizacion<Aldeano> &d);
void insertarPo(const Civilizacion<Aldeano> &d, int pos);
```

Pero tú intentas insertar un `Civilizacion<Aldeano> *`:

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Vas por buen camino, pero hay mucho espacio para mejorar.

- La clase `Nodo` debería ser una clase anidada en la zona privada de la clase `Lista`. Dudo mucho que se tenga la necesidad de crear nodos de datos que no estén relacionados con tu clase lista, para evitar su uso incorrecto (y ahorrarte la declaración `friend`) haz que `Nodo` forme parte de `Lista`.
- Te falta la corrección de constancia en clases. Tienen pinta de poder ser constantes

  - `int Lista::tamano()`
  - `string Civilizacion::getNombreC()`
  - `int Civilizacion::linearFindData(const T &)`
  - `int Civilizacion::poblacionT()`
  - `int Civilizacion::tamanio()`
  - `bool Civilizacion::isEmpty()`
- Deberían tener versión constante y no-constante.

  - `T &Lista::operator [](int)`
  - `T &Civilizacion::operator[](int)`
- Si tus civilizaciones sólo van a ser de aldeanos, no vale la pena que sea una clase plantilla.
- Es confuso usar abreviaciones o nombres cortos. Las personas que llevamos décadas programando recordamos la época en que las pantallas tenían 80 caracteres de ancho y 25 líneas de alto, entonces las variables y nombres de métodos cortos tenían sentido; hoy día es absurdo.
- Es confuso que el código mezcle inglés y español en los nombres de los métodos.
- **Nunca** incorpores la cláusula `using namespace std` en un archivo de cabecera, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%C3%A9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica) para más detalles al respecto.
- La mayoría de veces `std::endl` es innecesario e incluso contraproducente. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47839/c-instrucci%C3%B3n-endl) para más detalles al respecto.

#### Propuesta.

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior podrías corregir los errores de la siguiente manera:

```
MenuC::MenuC()
{
    string op;
    Lista<Civilizacion<Aldeano>> list;
    //                ~~~~~~~~~ <--- Es clase plantilla, requiere parametro plantilla

    while (true) {
        //Opciones del menu
        cout <<
        "1) Agregar civilizacion a la lista simplemente ligada\n"
        "2) Buscar civilizacion\n"
        "3) Eliminar civilizacion\n"
        "4) Mostrar civilizaciones\n"
        "Opcion: ";
        getline(cin, op);
        system("cls");

        if (op=="1") {
            Civilizacion<Aldeano> c;
            //                    ~ <--- Instancia local, no puntero
            c.setNombreC("Test");
            list.insertarIn(c);
        }else if(op=="2"){
        }else if (op=="3") {
        }else if (op=="4") {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder!. Entonces, de plano esta mal lo que estoy intentando hacer?, no logro entender cómo reservar la memoria y crear lo de civilización para después enlazarlo. En dado caso de que la clase plantilla guarde otros datos a futuro, sería necesario cambiarlo por los que me has mostrado tú?. Corregiré las constancias en las clases. Creó civ. a futuro guardara otras cosas. Entonces es buena practica dejar los nombres largos. Lo de inglés y español es mala practica de mi profesor, pero se contagia. No usare más el using en los archivos cabecera. Gracias por los enlaces.

Comment: @OscarD efectivamente, lo que estás intentando hacer es incorrecto; las plantillas no funcionan de la manera que las estás usando. Dado que veo que conservas dudas, editaré mi respuesta, aunque no acabo de entender las dudas que expresas en tu comentario.

Comment: La edición de tu respuesta ha solucionado los problemas =). Lo que pasa es que la actividad dice "La opciónn Agregar civilización a la lista simplemente ligada crear ́a un objeto apuntador
de la clase Civilización" y tiene una referencia a "Reutilizar la plantilla de la clase Lista desarrollada en el laboratorio para hacer una Lista<Civilizacion*>", ¿eso ayuda a entender un poco?, es la instrucción del profesor. @Paula_plus_plus

Answer (score 0):

Si te das cuenta, has puesto que has hecho el include

```
#include "civilizacion.h"
```

y según más abajo tu clase se llama

Civilización.h con C mayuscula.

el error que te da es que esperaba un tipo y se ha encontrado algo que no sabe lo que es (Civilizacion).Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Pero la clase civilización va con "C", veo a lo que te refieres pero eso lo puse por empezar la linea con mayúscula aquí, el include va con minúscula

Comment: No tiene por qué tener relación el nombre de la cabecera con el nombre de la(s) clase(s) que contenga; perfectamente podría ser que la cabecera `civilizacion.h` contenga el tipo `Civilizacion`. Por otro lado, el sistema de archivos podría no distinguir entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.