# ¿Cómo puedo guardar una lista ligada en un .txt?

Tags: c++, lista

Actividad escolar. Tengo una lista ligada la cual guarda archivos T, en mi caso son un objeto llamado Song, el cual tiene un autor, nombre, titulo y genero.
Quisiera que cada canción que esta en la lista se guarde en un archivo con el nombre de la canción y dentro del archivo los datos de la canción, autor, nombre, titulo y genero.

Así es cómo lo estoy intentando:

```
void Menu::saveSongs()
{
    cout << adminText << endl;
    if (myLista.isEmpty()) {
        cout << "-=ERROR: NO EXISTEN DATOS PARA GUARDAR=-" << endl << endl;
        return;
    }
    //Tiene que repetir el ciclo con otro archivo antes de entrar al archivo
    ofstream songsData("C:\\Users\\Oscar Diaz\\Documents\\QtProyectos\\Proyecto_ID\\Data\\Songs\\" + s.getName() +".txt", ios::out);
    if (songsData.is_open()) {
        for (int i(0); i < myLista.listSize(); i++) {
            songsData << s.getAuthor() << endl;
            songsData << s.getArtist() << endl;
            songsData << s.getName() << endl;
            songsData << s.getGenre() << endl;
        }
    }
    songsData.close();
    cout << "Mensaje prueba" ;
}
```

Entiendo mi problema pero no sé cómo resolverlo, necesito conseguir de canción por canción e ir la guardando. Si lo hago de la manera anterior toma los datos de la última canción que ingrese a la lista y la guarda dos veces en el mismo archivo ignorando completamente la primer canción ingresada, suponiendo que la lista sólo tiene 2 canciones.

cpp resumido:

```
[...]
List<Song> myLista; ///Lista ligada
Song s; ///Objeto song
string myStr; ///String para uso
Node<Song>* place; ///Nodo puntero para las búsquedas
[...]
void Menu::saveSongs()
{
    cout << adminText << endl;
    if (myLista.isEmpty()) {
        cout << "-=ERROR: NO EXISTEN DATOS PARA GUARDAR=-" << endl << endl;
        return;
    }
    //Tiene que repetir el ciclo con otro archivo antes de entrar al archivo
    ofstream songsData("C:\\Users\\Oscar Diaz\\Documents\\QtProyectos\\Proyecto_ID\\Data\\Songs\\" + s.getName() +".txt", ios::out);
    if (songsData.is_open()) {
        for (int i(0); i < myLista.listSize(); i++) {
            songsData << s.getAuthor() << endl;
            songsData << s.getArtist() << endl;
            songsData << s.getName() << endl;
            songsData << s.getGenre() << endl;
        }
    }
    songsData.close();
    cout << "Mensaje prueba" ;
}
```

Objeto Song:

```
#include "song.h"
using namespace std;

Song::Song(){}

Song::Song(const Song& s) : author(s.author), artist(s.artist), name(s.name), genre(s.genre){ }//< Constructor copia

string Song::getAuthor() const{
    return author;
}
void Song::setAuthor(const string &a){
    author = a;
}
string Song::getArtist() const{
    return artist;
}
void Song::setArtist(const string &r){
    artist = r;
}
string Song::getName() const{
    return name;
}
void Song::setName(const string &n){
    name = n;
}
string Song::getGenre() const{
    return genre;
}
void Song::setGenre(const string &g){
    genre = g;
}
string Song::toString(){
    string line = "-------------------------------------------------------------------";
    return "| " + name + "   |   " + artist + "   |   " + author + "   |   " + genre + "  |" + "\n" + line;

}
    Song& Song::operator=(const Song& s) {
        author = s.author;
        artist = s.artist;
        name = s.name;
        genre = s.genre;
        return *this;
    }
    ostream &operator << (ostream &o, Song &s){
        o << "+ Autor: " << s.getAuthor() << endl
          << "+ Artista: " << s.getArtist() << endl
          << "+ Nombre: " << s.getName() << endl
          << "+ Genero: " << s.getGenre() << endl
          << "+ Archivo a reproducir: " + s.getName() + " - " + s.getArtist() + ".mp3";
        return o;
    }
    istream& operator >> (istream& is, Song& s){
        getline(is, s.author);
        getline(is, s.artist);
        getline(is, s.name);
        getline(is, s.genre);
        return is;
    }
    bool Song::operator==(const Song& s) {
        return s.name == name;
    }
    bool Song::operator!=(const Song& s) {
        return s.name != name;
    }
    bool Song::operator<=(const Song&s) {
        return s.name <= name; //< Modificar
    }
    bool Song::operator>=(const Song&s) {
        return s.name >= name; //< Modificar
    }
    bool Song::operator<(const Song&s) {
        return s.name < name; //< Modificar
    }
    bool Song::operator>(const Song&s) {
        return s.name > name; //< Modificar
    }
```

Header de la lista ligada:

```
template<class T>
class List {
    private:
        Node<T>* anchor;
        int last;

        void copyAll(const List<T>&);

public:
    List();
    List(const List<T>&);
    ~List();

    bool isValidPos(Node<T>*);

    bool isEmpty();

    void insertData(Node<T>*, const T&);

    void deleteData(Node<T>*);

    Node<T>* getFirstPos();
    Node<T>* getLastPos();
    Node<T>* getPrevPos(Node<T>*);
    Node<T>* getNextPos(Node<T>*);

    Node<T>* findData(const T&);

    T retrieveData(Node<T>*);

    std::string toString();
    int listSize();

    void deleteAll();

    List<T>& operator = (const List<T>&);
    List<T>& operator [](int position);

};

template<class T>
void List<T>::copyAll(const List<T>& l) {
    Node<T> *aux(l.anchor), *lastInserted(nullptr), *newNode;

    while (aux!= nullptr) {
        newNode = new Node<T>(aux->getData());
        if(newNode == nullptr){
            throw ListException("memoria no disponible, crear nuevo nodo, intentar copiar");
        }

        if(lastInserted == nullptr){
            anchor = newNode;
        }else{
            lastInserted->setNext(newNode);
        }

        lastInserted = newNode;

        aux = aux->getNext();
        }
    }

template<class T>
bool List<T>::isValidPos(Node<T>* p)    {
    Node<T>* aux(anchor);

    while(aux != nullptr) {
        if(aux == p) {
            return true;
            }
        aux=aux->getNext();
        }
    return false;
    }

template<class T>
List<T>::List() : anchor(nullptr) { }

template<class T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& l) : anchor(nullptr) {
    copyAll(l);
    }

template<class T>
List<T>::~List() {
    deleteAll();
    }

template<class T>
bool List<T>::isEmpty() {
    return anchor==nullptr;
    }

template<class T>
void List<T>::insertData(Node<T>* p, const T& e) {
    if(p!=nullptr and !isValidPos(p)) {
        throw ListException("Posicion invalida, tratando de insertar");
        }

    Node<T>* aux(new Node<T>(e));

    if(aux == nullptr) {
        throw ListException("memoria no disponible, crando nodo, tratano de insertar");
        }

    if(p == nullptr) {
        aux->setNext(anchor);
        anchor = aux;
        }
    else {
        aux->setNext(p->getNext());
        p->setNext(aux);
        }
    last++;

    }

template<class T>
void List<T>::deleteData(Node<T>* p) {

    if(!isValidPos(p)) {
        throw ListException("La posicion es invalida, tratando de eliminar");
        }

    if(p == anchor) {
        anchor = anchor->getNext();
        }
    else {
        getPrevPos(p)->setNext(p->getNext());
        }
    delete p;
    last--;
    }

template<class T>
Node<T>* List<T>::getFirstPos() {
    return anchor;
    }

template<class T>
Node<T>* List<T>::getLastPos() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return nullptr;
        }

    Node<T>* aux(anchor);

    while(aux->getNext() != nullptr) {
        aux = aux->getNext();
        }
    return aux;
    }

template<class T>
Node<T>* List<T>::getPrevPos(Node<T>* p) {
    Node<T>* aux(anchor);

    while(aux != nullptr and aux->getNext() != p) {
        aux = aux->getNext();
        }
    return aux;
    }

template<class T>
Node<T>* List<T>::getNextPos(Node<T>* p) {
    if(!isValidPos(p)) {
        return nullptr;
        }
    return p->getNext();
    }

template<class T>
Node<T>* List<T>::findData(const T& e) {
    Node<T>* aux(anchor);

    while(aux != nullptr and aux->getData()!= e) {
        aux = aux->getNext();
        }

    return aux;
    }

template<class T>
T List<T>::retrieveData(Node<T>* p) {
    if(!isValidPos(p)) {
        throw ListException("Posicion invalida, haciendo retrieve");
        }

    return p->getData();
    }

template<class T>
std::string List<T>::toString() {
    std::string result;
    Node<T>* aux(anchor);

    while(aux != nullptr) {
        result += aux->getData().toString() + "\n";

        aux = aux->getNext();
        }
    return result;
    }
template<class T>
int List<T>::listSize(){
    return last;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::deleteAll() {
   Node<T>* aux;

    while(anchor != nullptr) {
        aux=anchor;

        anchor = anchor->getNext();

        delete aux;
        }
    }

template<class T>
List<T>& List<T>::operator=(const List<T>& other) {
    this->deleteAll();

    this->copyAll(other);

    return *this;

}

template<class T>
List<T> &List<T>::operator [](int position)
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw ListException("La lista esta vacia");
    }
    Node<T>* aux(anchor);
    int cont = 0;

    while (aux != nullptr) {
        if (cont++ == position) {
            return aux->getData();
        }
        aux = aux->getNext();
    }

}

#endif // LIST_H_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Si lo hago de la manera anterior toma los datos de la última canción que ingrese a la lista y la guarda dos veces en el mismo archivo.

Es posible que tenga que ver con que no estés haciendo nada por recorrer tu lista. Te invito a repasar tu función `Menu::saveSongs`:

```
void Menu::saveSongs()
{
    cout << adminText << endl;
    if (myLista.isEmpty()) {
        cout << "-=ERROR=-\n\n";
        return;
    }

    ofstream songsData("..." + s.getName() +".txt", ios::out);
    if (songsData.is_open()) {
        for (int i(0); i < myLista.listSize(); i++) {
//               ~     ~                       ~ <--- Iteramos sobre 'i' pero
//                                                    no se usa 'i' para indizar
            songsData << s.getAuthor() << endl;
            songsData << s.getArtist() << endl;
            songsData << s.getName() << endl;
            songsData << s.getGenre() << endl;
//                       ~ <--- ¿De dónde sale 's'?
        }
    }
    songsData.close();
}
```

Si te fijas, recorres los elementos de tu lista, pero siempre accedes al mismo elemento que parece ser una variable global. Atendiendo a tu implementación de `List`, seguramente deberías usar el operador de indizado, pero éste tiene serios problemas:

```
template<class T>
   List<T> &List<T>::operator [](int position)
// ~~~~~~~~~ <--- ¿Devuelve un objeto lista? ¡Debería devolver un objeto 'T'!
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw ListException("La lista esta vacia");
    }
    Node<T>* aux(anchor);
    int cont = 0;

    while (aux != nullptr) {
        if (cont++ == position) {
            return aux->getData();
        }
        aux = aux->getNext();
    }
// ¡Se acaba la función sin devolver nada!.
}
```

El tipo de retorno del operador de indizado es una lista, lo cuál no tiene ningún sentido... es como si vas a una zapatería y te llevas una caja de zapatos que tiene una zapatería dentro, extraño ¿verdad?. El operador de indizado debería devolver el tipo almacenado en la lista ¡no una lista!.

#### Correcciones.

El operador de indizado de `List` debe devolver `T`:

```
template<class T>
T &List<T>::operator [](int position)
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw ListException("La lista esta vacia");
    }

    Node<T>* aux(anchor);

    while ((aux != nullptr) && (cont != position)) {
        aux = aux->getNext();
    }

    return aux->getData();
}
```

Ahora con esta corrección tu función `Menu::saveSongs` podría quedar así:

```
void Menu::saveSongs()
{
    cout << adminText << '\n';
    if (myLista.isEmpty()) {
        cout << "-=ERROR: NO EXISTEN DATOS PARA GUARDAR=-\n\n";
        return;
    }

    if (ofstream songsData{"C:\\...\\" + s.getName() +".txt"}) {
        for (int i(0); i < myLista.listSize(); ++i) {
            const &the_song = myLista[i];
//                            ~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Accedemos al elemento i-esimo

            songsData << the_song.getAuthor() << '\n'
                      << the_song.getArtist() << '\n'
                      << the_song.getName() << '\n'
                      << the_song.getGenre() << '\n';
        }
    }

    cout << "Mensaje prueba\n";
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- **No abuses de `using namespace std`**: Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%C3%A9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica) para saber más al respecto.
- **Intenta no abusar de `std::endl`**: Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47839/c-instrucci%C3%B3n-endl) para saber más al respecto.
- **Favorece el pre-incremento frente al post-incremento**: Lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para saber más al respecto.
- **`std::ofstream` es de salida**: Por defecto, [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) abre el archivo para salida de datos, no es necesario indicarlo explícitamente.
- **`std::ofstream` sigue el patrón RAII**: El objeto `std::ofstream` sigue el patrón de diseño [RAII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII), de manera que automáticamente libera los recursos que maneja al destruirse. Por lo tanto no necesitas invocar `close`, pues se cierra automáticamente.
- **Tu algoritmo de escritura tiene complejidad O(n!)**: Por cada elemento del que escribes un archivo, recorres todos los elementos anteriores (por cómo está implementado el operador de indizado), lo que nos da una complejidad factorial; plantea la posibilidad de implementar [iteradores](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterador).

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, tus respuestas son geniales. `s` viene de un objeto declarado `Song s;`. Es por eso que siempre devolvia el valor del último insertado. En las correcciones que me hiciste que es `const &the_song`, intente poner `const Song &sa = myLista[i];` pero obtengo un error: _C:\...\list.h:271: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Song&' from an rvalue of type 'Song'
     return aux->getData();
                         ^_  @Paula_plus_plus

Comment: Muchas gracias de igual manera por los consejos @Paula_plus_plus

Comment: Perdona @OscarD no vi tu última duda. No puedo analizar el error que obtienes sin conocer la definición de `getData`.