# cannot convert `int*' to `Comercio*' for argument `1' to `void pedirdatos(Comercio*)

Tags: c++

¿A qué se debe este error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct Comercio{
    int codigo,cactual,cminima;
    float precio;
    string descripcion;
};
int i,n;
void pedirdatos(Comercio *v);
int *v;

int main(){

    cout<<"Ingrese cantidad de articulos: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    v= new Comercio[n];

    pedirdatos(v,n);

    return 0;   
}

void pedirdatos(Comercio *v){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        cout << "Ingrese codigo:" <<endl;

        cin >>v[i].codigo;
        cout<< "Ingrese descripcion: "<<endl;
        fflush(stdin);
        cin>>v[i].descripcion;
        cout<< "Cantidad actual: "<<endl;
        cin>> v[i].cactual;
        cout<< "Cantidad minima: "<<endl;
        cin>> v[i].cminima;
        cout<< "Precio:  "<<endl;
        cin>>v[i].precio;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

El error es claro, conciso y autoexplicativo:

```
cannot convert `int*' to `Comercio*' for argument `1' to `void pedirdatos(Comercio*)`
```

Tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

```
no se puede convertir `int*' a `Comercio*' para el argumento `1' de `void pedirdatos(Comercio*)
```

El punto donde estás llamndo a `pedirdatos` es en esta línea:

```
pedirdatos(v,n);
```

El argumento 1 es `v`, que vemos que está definido en esta línea:

```
int *v;
```

Así que `v` es de tipo `int *`, ¿qué espera `pedirdatos` como primer argumento?, veamos su declaración:

```
void pedirdatos(Comercio *v);
```

El primer argumento de `pedirdatos` es de tipo `Comercio *`. Y ahí está el error: No se puede convertir un dato de tipo puntero a entero (`int *`) a un dato de tipo puntero a Comercio.

Pero ese es el menor de tus problemas, tu código es incorrecto por muchos otros motivos:

- Las cabeceras [`<stdio.h>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io), [`<stdlib.h>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header), [`<string.h>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) y [`<ctype.h>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) son de [c](/questions/tagged/c) no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Estas cabeceras disponen de una versión adaptada a C++ que tiene el prefijo **`c`** y carece de extensión. Si realmente necesitas usar las cabeceras de C (que nunca será el caso) debes usar los equivalentes de C++ [`<cstdio>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio), [`<cstdlib>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib), [`<cstring>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring) y [`<cctype>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype). Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber por qué.
- Además de que incluyes dos veces `<stdio.h>`, no estás utilizando ninguna de su utilidaes, así que no necesitarías incluirla ni siquiera una sola vez. Tampoco usas nada de `<stdlib.h>` ni `<ctype.h>` así que su inclusión es también innecesaria.
- Incluyes la cabecera de cadenas de C `<string.h>` y la de C++ `<string>` pero sólo usas la segunda así que la primera inclusión es innecesaria.
- No hay obligación de usar la cláusula `using namespace std;` pues es sólo es una ayuda a la escritura de código; si decides usar esta cláusula no lo hagas en el ámbito global, úsala en el ámbito más pequeño posible. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber por qué.
  Evita abusar de [`std::endl` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) (pues puede causar problemas de rendimiento) y favorece el uso del salto de línea explícito (`\n`). Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/2742) para saber por qué.
- Declaras y defines `pedirdatos` con un solo argumento, pero la usas con dos.
- Usas memoria dinámica y no la borras. Cambia a un contenedor de datos.
- Deja a tu código respirar, añade unos espacios y saltos de línea. En los 90 teníamos pantallas de 80 caracteres de ancho y 25 líneas de alto, por entonces tenía sentido apretujar el código para que cupiera en la pantalla. Hoy día tenemos pantallas enormes y separar las cosas hace que el código sea más legible.
- Los nombres de tus variables o tipos no son autoexplicativos; los nombres deberían permitir saber de un vistazo su cometido, haciendo que el código sea menos propenso a errores y haciendo que sea más fácil de leer y entender, cosa que cualquier persona que trabaje contigo (incluso tu yo futuro) agradecerá mucho.

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Comercio{
    int codigo = 0, cactual = 0, cminima = 0;
    float precio = 0f;
    std::string descripcion = "";
};

void pedirdatos(std::vector<Comercio> &comercios) {

    using namespace std;

    for (auto &comercio : comercios) {

        cout << "Ingrese codigo:\n";
        cin >> comercio.codigo;

        cout << "Ingrese descripcion: \n";
        cin >> comercio.descripcion;

        cout << "Cantidad actual: \n";
        cin >> comercio.cactual;

        cout << "Cantidad minima: \n";
        cin >> comercio.cminima;

        cout << "Precio:  \n";
        cin >> comercio.precio;
    }
}

int main() {

    using namespace std;

    int cantidad;
    cout << "Ingrese cantidad de articulos: \n";
    cin >> cantidad;

    vector<Comercio> comercios(cantidad);
    pedirdatos(comercios);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas asignando un tipo de valor diferente al que has declarado en la variable **v**.

La haz declarado como `int*`.

```
Int *v
```

Pero aquí le agregas un valor de tipo `Comercio`.

```
v= new Comercio[n];
```

Puedes solucionarlo si declaras la variable de esta manera:

```
Comercio* v;
```

Comment: No entiendo por que sale este error cannot convert `Comercio*' to `int*' in assignment

Comment: pedirdatos(v); pruebalo así

Comment: No, mejor agrega un parametro a tu metodo: void pedirdatos(Comercio *v, int n)

Comment: sigue tirando error en la linea 28 :(

Comment: Ahhh ya v= new Comercio[n]; ahi esta tu error?

Comment: Es que no hay que declararla como `Comercio[]` Sino como `Comercio*`. Las llaves son para arrays de tamaño fijo y, ello te obliga a declarar **sí o sí** el tamaño en tiempo de compilación: `Comercio v[10]`. Sobre un array de tamaño fijo no puede usarse ni `new` ni `delete`. Por favor, arregla esa última línea.