# Dos números diferentes se consideran iguales en comparación

Tags: c++

Al compilar el siguiente programa en CodeBlocks me sale este mensaje:

> Ambos números son iguales

Aunque no lo sean. ¿por qué puede suceder eso?

Éste es el código:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
 int main(){
 float n1,n2,n3;
 cout<<"Escriba tres numeros: "<<endl;
 cin>>n1>>n2>>n3;


 if ((n1=n2=n3)){
    cout<<"Ambos numeros son iguales";
 }
else if ((n1>n2)and(n1>n3)){
  cout<<"el mayor es: "<<n1;
 }
 else if ((n2>n1)and(n2>n3)){
  cout<<"el mayor es: "<<n2;
 }
 else {cout<<"el mayor es: "<<n3;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Porque estás usando `=` en lugar de `==`. Un solo `=` es una asignación en vez de una comparación. Como parte de una expresión booleana, toma el valor `true` si lo asignado es distinto de cero.

Comment: un signo de igual `=` es asignar; por ejemplo `a = 10` aqui decimos que a vale 10, por el contrario aqui `10 == 10` verificamos si ambos valores son iguales

Answer (score 7):

El error está en la condición:

> if ((n1=n2=n3))

Porque un **=** se considera un operador de asignación y lo que intentas es comparar valores y el operador para realizar una comparación sería **==**. Además, tienes que recordar que tienes que evaluar los tres por esa razón te escribí esto:

> if ((n1==n2 && n1==n3 && n2==n3))

Te comparto tu código, nada más tiene un do..while para que la prueba sea mas fácil de realizar.

Esté sería tu código funcionando:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
 int main(){
     float n1,n2,n3;
     int op;
     do
     {
         cout<<"Escriba primer numero: ";
         cin>>n1;
         cout<<"\nEscriba segundo numero: ";
         cin>>n2;
         cout<<"\nEscriba tercer numero: ";
         cin>>n3;


         if ((n1==n2 && n1==n3 && n2==n3)){
                cout<<"\nAmbos numeros son iguales";
            }
        else if ((n1>n2)&&(n1>n3)){
                cout<<"\nel mayor es: "<<n1;
            }
        else if ((n2>n1)&&(n2>n3)){
                cout<<"\nel mayor es: "<<n2;
            }
        else {
                cout<<"\nel mayor es: "<<n3;
            }

            cout<<"\n\n 1 - Salir";
            cout<<"\n 0 - Continuar";
            cout <<"\n\t Opcion: ";
            cin>>op;
    }

    while(op!=1);
    return 0;
}
```

Pero te recomendaría algo como esto (si lo que intentas es encontrar el mayor):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int numero, mayor, op;
    do
    {
        cout << "\nIntroduzca el primer n%cmero (entero): ";
        cin >> mayor;
        cout << "\nIntroduzca el segundo n%cmero (entero): ";
        cin >> numero;

        if ( numero > mayor )
            mayor = numero;
         cout << "\nIntroduzca el tercer n%cmero (entero): " ;
         cin >> numero;
        if ( numero > mayor )
            mayor = numero;
         cout << "\n el mayor es: " <<  numero;


        cout<<"\n\n 1 - Salir";
        cout<<"\n 0 - Continuar";
        cout <<"\n\t Opcion: ";
        cin>>op;
    }
    while(op!=1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: se te agradece el apoyo pero solo poner código en la respuesta se considera de baja calidad, dale editar y añade la explicación de por que esto es una respuesta

Comment: Espero se entienda un poco mejor ahora.

Comment: Solamente lo había escrito más descriptivo. Pero gracias, espero os sea de ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Se agradece que seas descriptivo en las respuestas. Poner solo la solución y que el resto tenga que adivinar por qué lo tuyo funciona y lo suyo no suele ser de demasiada ayuda

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta de [SourceCode](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/213409/2742) es muy buena, pero querría añadir detalles que no ha comentado.

Para empezar, quiero señalar un problema semántico: estás comparando **TRES** números pero tu mensaje de error se refiere a **DOS**:

```
cout<<"Ambos numeros son iguales";
```

El mensaje no debería mencionar `Ambos`, es muy confuso (y una fuente de errores comunes) que el código diga una cosa y la información que aparece por pantalla diga otra.

#### Comparaciones.

Seguidamente, como te han señalado, la instrucción `(n1=n2=n3)` no compara los tres números, esa instrucción se desglosa de derecha a izquierda así:

1. Asigna a `n2` el valor de `n3`.
2. Devuelve `n2`.
3. Asigna a `n1` el valor de `n2`.
4. Devuelve `n1`.

Así que al final de la instrucción los tres números tendrán el valor de `n3` pero eso no es lo que hace que se cumpla la condición `if ((n1=n2=n3))` si no el hecho de que `n1` no es `0`.

Al final de la instrucción de doble asignación se devuelve `n1` (que ha recibido el valor de `n2` que ha recibido el valor de `n3`) en C++ cualquier expresión numérica puede ser convertida implícitamente a una [expresión booleana [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression) siguiendo las siguientes normas:

- Si el valor de la expresión numérica **es** `0` se considera que su valor booleano es `false`.
- Si el valor de la expresión **no es** `0` se considera que su valor booleano es `true`.

Por lo tanto, si en tu código hubieses dado valor `0` a `n3` no se habría cumplido la condición `if ((n1=n2=n3))` ya que `n1` (que recibió el valor de `n2` que recibió el valor de `n3`)  sería `0` y se consideraría `false`.

Si quieres comprobar si los tres valores son iguales, basta con comparar el primero con el segundo y el segundo con el tercero usando el operador de comparación (`==`) (no el de asignación (`=`)) y enlazando la comparación con un Y lógico (`&&`):

```
if (n1 == n2 && n2 == n3)
    cout << "Los números son iguales\n";
```

Nunca podrás comprobar si los tres valores son iguales encadenando tres operadores de comparación (`==`):

```
if (n1 == n2 == n3) // Esto no funciona!
```

Ya que la instrucción anterior se desglosa de derecha a izquierda así:

1. Compara `n2` (de tipo `float`) con `n3` (de tipo `float`).
2. Devuelve un valor booleano.
3. Compara `n1` (de tipo `float`) con un valor booleano (de tipo `bool`).
4. Convierte `n1` a `bool` siguiendo las normas mencionadas antes.
5. Compara `n1` convertido a `bool` con el booleano de la primera comparación.

De esta manera, si `n2` y `n3` son iguales y `n1` no es `0` se cumplirá la condición aunque `n1` sea diferente a `n2` y `n3`.

#### El máximo.

Es tremendamente confuso encadenar comparaciones para determinar cuál es el mayor de una serie de números, yo aconsejo usar la función [`std::max` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max), tu código podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    float n1, n2, n3;
    cout << "Escriba tres numeros: \n";
    cin >> n1 >> n2 >> n3;

    if (n1 == n2 && n2 == n3) {
        cout << "Los numeros son iguales\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "El mayor es: " << max(n1, max(n2, n3)) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Avanzado.

Si quieres generalizar la comprobación de valores y la búsqueda del máximo para que reciban una cantidad arbitraria de parámetros, podrías usar plantillas variádicas:

```
template <typename T, typename ... VALORES>
T multi_max(const T &valor, const VALORES & ... valores)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(VALORES) == 0)
        return valor;
    else
        return std::max(valor, multi_max(valores ...));
}

template <typename T, typename ... VALORES>
bool todos_iguales(const T &a, const T &b, const VALORES & ... valores)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(VALORES) == 0)
        return a == b;
    else if constexpr (sizeof...(VALORES) == 1)
        return a == b && todos_iguales(b, valores ...);
    else
        return a == b && todos_iguales(valores ...);
}
```

Así:

```
if (todos_iguales(n1, n2, n3) {
    cout << "Los numeros son iguales\n";
}
else {
    cout << "El mayor es: " << multi_max(n1, n2, n3) << '\n';
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

A parte de corregir la primera comparación y usar `max` para buscar el máximo he hecho los siguientes cambios:

- He movido la cláusula `using namespace std;` a `main`. Es una buena práctica evitar usar esa cláusula en el ámbito global, úsala en el ámbito más pequeño posible. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber por qué.
- He substituido [`std::endl` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) por `\n` ya que puede causar problemas de rendimiento. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/2742) para saber por qué.
- He añadido mayor separación en los símbolos para dejar al código respirar. En los 90 teníamos pantallas de 80 caracteres de ancho y 25 líneas de alto, por entonces tenía sentido apretujar el código para que cupiera en la pantalla. Hoy día tenemos pantallas enormes y separar las cosas hace que el código sea más legible.

Comment: Usted tiene lo de "En los 90 teníamos pantallas de 80..." pegado en archivo de bloc de notas, no? xD

Comment: Así es @Xam , esa frase y otras muchas.