# Ordenar una lista por numeros enteros

Tags: c++

Tengo una programa que debe insertar un polinomio y a la vez, en caso de que se requiera agregar un nuevo término de un termino que ya se encuentre en el polinomio, se deberá de sumar al coeficiente existente.

Por ejemplo, si inserto un termino, con coeficiente 1 y despues el grado 1, al mostrar la lista debe quedar asi "+1x^1", pero al insertar otro termino con coeficiente 1 y grado 1 de nuevo, al mostrar los elementos se debe mostrar "+2x^1" y al final ya cuando se inserta un termino con coeficiente 2 y grado 3, la lista debe quedar "+2x^3+2x^1"

Mi problema es que no se cómo hacer que cuando se inserte un coeficiente nuevo se sume al que tiene el mismo grado, además de que mi lista se muestra de diferente manera y debo ordenar dicha lista de mayor a menor

**Polinomio.h**

```
#ifndef POLINOMIO
#define POLINOMIO

class Polinomio{
public: 
    int coeficiente;
    int grado;
};
#endif
```

**menu.h**

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <list>
#include "Polinomio.h"
using namespace std;
list<Polinomio> polinomio;

int menu() {
    int opcionElegida = 0;
    do {
        cout << "1) Agregar termino" << endl;
        cout << "2) Mostrar polinomio" << endl;
        cout << "3) Salir" << endl;
        cout << "Opcion:" << endl;
        cin>>opcionElegida;
        if (opcionElegida <= 0 || opcionElegida > 3) {
            cout << "\tOpcion invalida" << endl;
        } else {
            break;
        }

    } while (true);
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    return opcionElegida;
}


void agregarTermino() {

    Polinomio newPoli;
    cout<<"Coeficiente: "<<endl;
    cin>>newPoli.coeficiente;
    cout<<"Grado:"<<endl;
    cin>>newPoli.grado;
    polinomio.push_back(newPoli);

}

void mostrarPoli() {

    list<Polinomio>::iterator a1;
    for(a1 = polinomio.begin(); a1!= polinomio.end() ; *a1++){
        Polinomio a = *a1;
        cout<<"+x"<<a.coeficiente<<"^"<<a.grado<<endl;
    }

}

void ejecutaOpcionElegida(int opcion) {
    switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            agregarTermino();
            break;
        case 2:
            mostrarPoli();
            break;
        case 3:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
}

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
#include "menu.h"

int main() {
    int opcion=0;
    do {
        opcion = menu();
        ejecutaOpcionElegida(opcion);
    } while (opcion != 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> no se como hacer que cuando se inserte un coeficiente nuevo se sume al que tiene el mismo grado

Tu código se limita a insertar sin mas al final de la lista; claramente, eso dista mucho de sumar: tienes que buscar ([`std::find( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)) si ya existe un dato con ese grado.

```
#include <algorithm>

void agregarTermino( ) {
  Polinomio newPoli;

  cout << "Coeficiente: " << endl;
  cin >> newPoli.coeficiente;
  cout << "Grado:" << endl;
  cin >> newPoli.grado;

  // Buscamos si ya hay 1 polinomio con ese grado.
  auto prev = std::find( polinomio.begin( ), polinomio.end( ), [&newPoli]( const Polinomio &p ){ return p.grado == newPoli.grado; } );

  if( prev == polinomio.end( ) {
    polinomio.push_back( newPoli );
  } else {
    prev->coeficiente += newPoli.coeficiente;
  }
}
```

> debo ordenar dicha lista de mayor a menor

Aun mas simple, puesto que [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) **ya tiene** una función-miembro [`sort( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort):

```
void mostrarPoli( ) {
  // Ordenamos la lista.
  polinomio.sort( []( const Polinomio &p1, const Polinomio &p2 ){ return p1.grado > p2.grado; } );

  for( auto iter : polinomio ) {
    cout << "+x" << a.coeficiente << "^" << a.grado << '\n';
  }
}
```

<sub>**No lo he probado** pero, salvo cambios mínimos, **debería** funcionar.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

No te será posible ordenar si el programa no tiene manera de averiguar si un `Polinomio` es mayor, menor o igual a otro. Para solucionar este problema debemos hacer que `Polinomio` cumpla con el requisito de [*ser comparable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) que en general basta con implementar el operador menor-que:

```
class Polinomio{
public:
    bool operator<(const Polinomio &p) const { return p.grado < grado; }
    int coeficiente;
    int grado;
};
```

Y ya puedes ordenar:

```
polinomio.sort();
```

#### Propuesta.

Pero si el orden y la uasencia de duplicados es importante, entonces te has equivocado de contenedor, en realidad necesitas un mapa, no una lista:

```
using Polinomio = std::map<int, int>;

void agregarTermino(Polinomio &p) {

    int coeficiente, grado;

    std::cout << "Coeficiente:\n";
    std::cin >> coeficiente;

    std::cout << "Grado:\n";
    std::cin >> grado;

    auto [termino, insercion] = p.insert({grado, 0});
    termino->second += coeficiente;
}
```

El código anterior inserta un elemento en el mapa indexando por grado; si ya existe un elemento en ese grado le suma el coeficiente. Se puede usar así:

```
int main()
{
    Polinomio p;
    agregarTermino(p);
    agregarTermino(p);
    agregarTermino(p);

    for (const auto &termino : p)
        std::cout << "+x" << termino.second << "^" << termino.first;

    return 0;
}
```

Que con tus datos de ejemplo muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> +x2^1+x2^3
> ```

Para mostrarlo en el orden que necesitas, basta con iterar el mapa en sentido inverso:

```
for (auto termino = p.rbegin(); termino != p.rend(); ++termino)
    std::cout << "+x" << termino->second << "^" << termino->first;
```

Puedes ver este código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/09CMUwQGWfTrjmzm).

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Procura favorecer el uso de `'\n'` frente al uso de `std::endl` ya que este último puede en ocasiones causar problemas de rendimiento. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/2742) para saber más al respecto.
- No debes incluir `<string.h>`; no sólo no la estás usando si no que además de que se trata de una cabecera del lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c) (y estás programando en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)). Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber más al respecto.
- No debes incluir `<cstdlib>` ya que no la estás usando. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber más al respecto.