# ¿Cómo llamar a cada elemento de un array en C++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy desarrollando un programa que averigua si entre los números ingresados por el usuario hay algún primo. Estos números se almacenan en un arreglo, pero no sé cómo invocar a cada uno.

Lo intenté con un ciclo:

```
#include<iostream>

int primo[10];
int cont = 0;

using namespace std;

int main (){

    cout<<"Ingrese los numeros a validar:"<<endl;
    for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
    cin>>primo[10];
    }

    for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
            for(int j= 1; j<=primo[i]; j++)
            if(primo[i]%j == 0){
                cont++;
            }

          if(cont==2){
          cout<<"Este es primo";
          } else {
            cout<<"Este no es primo";
          }

         return 0;

}
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que el iterador i vaya tomando los valores de cada una de las posiciones del arreglo, para que por ejemplo si el primer valor es 17 es programa vaya a esa ubicación i =0 (o sea 17) y empiece a dividir entre todos los valores j (desde 1 hasta el propio 17); si solo encuentra dos módulos 0 (o sea cuando divide entre 1 y el propio 17) quiere decir que es primo, de lo contrario no lo es.

El programa funciona cuando ingresas de a un número (es decir, cuando no ocupo un arreglo sino que creo diez variables), el método para saber si es primo o no es correcto, pero la verdad no sé como llamar a cada uno de los números que se alojan en el arreglo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varias cosas.
Primero me da gusto que te interesaras en la programación y no te preocupes por las preguntas todos pasamos por ahí al principio.

Luego te recomiendo que mejores el uso de la sangría pues ayuda a identificar mas fácilmente los problemas.

Tu problema se encontraba en el uso de los `for` ya que el primero no hacia uso de la variable `i` por lo que todos los números ingresados se alojaban en la posición 10, así mismo el `return` colocado en esa posición hacia que la ejecución terminara después del primer ciclo.

```
#include<iostream>

int primo[10];

int cont = 0;

using namespace std;

int main (){

     cout<<"Ingrese los numeros a validar:"<<endl;
     for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
       //Se debe especificar que se accede a cada elemento del arreglo usando la variable i
      cin>>primo[i];
     }

      for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
       //Para cada ciclo se de reiniciar el contador o de lo contrario se seguira incrementando
       cont = 0;

       for(int j= 1; j<=primo[i]; j++)
         if(primo[i]%j == 0)
             cont++;

       cout<<primo[i];

       if(cont==2){
         cout<<"  es primo\n";
       } else {
         cout<<"  no es primo\n";
       }

  }

  //Para este caso es necesario que el retorno se encuentre al final de la realizacion del ciclo
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me ayudaste a entender cómo debía hacerlo. Y gracias por la buena vibra :D

Answer (score 0):

Incluyo aquí una versión de tu código que logra lo que quieres. Ahora, antes de leerlo, te invito a que primero intentes corregir por tu cuenta los errores que te menciono aquí, y que luego pases a ver mi código. Es como mejor aprenderás, pienso yo.

1. El `return 0;` está dentro de un `for`. Esto no puede ser así, esa línea tiene que ser lo último que aparece en la función `main`.
2. En el primer `for`, estas guardando el valor que ingresa el usuario en el decimo lugar del arreglo cada vez, en vez de ir guardándolos en los espacios correspondientes.
3. El `for` con la `j` no tiene los corchetes que definen lo que cubre.
4. No estás reiniciando la variable `cont` a que sea igual a `0` luego de cumplir su función con un candidato a primo en particular.

---

Ahora, mientras vayas leyendo el código, por favor, presta atención a los siguientes puntos:

**El formato** - Puede parecer mera pedantería, pero atenerse a buenas práctica de formato verdaderamente ayuda. Colocar los niveles anidados con el sangrado (indentación, como decimos en la calle) correcto permite ver la estructura del programa a simple vista, disminuye el esfuerzo mental que uno invierte en interpretar el programa, y libera más potencia mental para el problema en sí.

**Los comentarios** - Ayuda a todos: A ti a organizar tus pensamientos, y a otros lectores (incluso al ti del futuro) a entender qué pasaba por tu mente cuando lo escribiste.

Aquí está:

```
#include<iostream>

const int CANTIDAD_DE_PRIMOS = 10;
int primo[CANTIDAD_DE_PRIMOS];
int cont = 0;

using namespace std;

int main () {

    cout << "Ingrese los numeros a validar:" << endl;

    // Solicita al usuario que ingrese números, los cuales se van guardando en un arreglo
    for (int i = 0 ; i < CANTIDAD_DE_PRIMOS ; i++) {
        cin >> primo[i];
    }

    // Itera sobre el arreglo de primos
    for (int i = 0 ; i < CANTIDAD_DE_PRIMOS ; i++) {

        // Empieza en 0 la cantidad de factores que tiene el posible primo
        cont = 0; 

        // Itera sobre todos los números menores que el posible primo
        for (int j = 1 ; j <= primo[i] ; j++) {

            // Verifica si el número j es factor del primo; si lo es, aumenta el contador de factores
            if (primo[i] % j == 0) {
                cont++;
            }
        }

        // Si el número tiene dos factores, es primo; de lo contrario, no lo es
        if (cont == 2) {
            cout << primo[i] << " es primo" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << primo[i] << " no es primo" << endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RafaelLopez La forma de agradecer es [aceptando la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) que resolvió tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes serios errores de concepto que hacen difícil entender lo que pides.

- En C++ los únicos tipos de datos que pueden ser "*llamados*" son las funciones, los funtores y las lambdas, no puedes "*llamar*" a un elemento de un array, lo puedes leer o escribir.
- Tampoco se pueden "*invocar*".
- Un iterador es un concepto que hace referencia a un objeto que equivale a un elemento de una colección de datos y puede moverse por dicha colección, tú estás hablando de índices.

Una vez aclarados los puntos anteriores, unos consejos:

- Evita las variables globales, úsalas sólo cuando sea estrictamente necesario, no es tu caso con `primo` ni `cont`.
- Se aconseja que las variables estén lo más cercanas posibles a su punto de uso, esto se relaciona con el punto anterior.
- Puedes hacer que tu código sea más fácil de entender y más cómodo de mantener si lo modularizas, separa algunas acciones en funciones.
- Procura no abusar de la cláusula `using namespace` en ámbito global. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber más del tema.
- Procura no abusar de `std::endl`. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/2742) para saber más del tema.

Siguiendo esos consejos, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>

bool es_primo(int numero) {
    // Todos los números son divisibles por 1, no es necesario comprobarlo.
    for (int divisor = 2; divisor != numero; ++divisor)
        if (!(numero % divisor))
            // Si es divisible por un número, ya no es primo.
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    // Se aconseja que las cláusulas 'using' estén en el menor ámbito posible.
    using namespace std;

    int primo[10];

    cout << "Ingrese los numeros a validar:\n";
    // Usando el for de rango, el código es más claro y fácil de mantener.
    for (auto &numero : primo) {
        cin >> numero;
    }

    // Ahora usamos const porque no queremos modificar el valor.
    for (const auto &numero : primo) {
        cout << numero << (es_primo(numero) ? "" : " no") << " es primo\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El código es aún mejorable: no es necesario comprobar los divisores de `numero` hasta `numero` pues después del valor de su raíz cuadrada no tendrá más divisores.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJNbxMxEIbP618xXQRN1NJm89E0TVrEkXPhBAhNvE4wsseLva5UVfyYHDlz47o/LIz3I0e0n@Ox/T7zjmVVvZUGaX88vtIkTSwVbLQLtVdoH4TYOmdAhW@V19aNNNVA0SrvxvAisutr@OhKF8DwQ83flAgQHEGpn3TQW6MCVM5DcQnkeBsgJVVArx1IZyvvtuiNuxLZjie1u7cLObiH6foUnN33qmu4uOgHxyLL9A5GZ6MuBa@H6eOUSmyPOkmeUFqSSAPoJTxjT9UWd5VWeVVHT7BDE9RaDGHtI0e/hEiEFjWNxqIr/1EBSkdB/UD4GRUYDCBNc4ghpt/zGDTtz1mjbn4TKL4NWEUM0hzsVteOoVo4Vm/nAqFVoUKpINTlWogsabaAn4vJ1zQgXaxhs4H8A@29CqpzP3bmIzyh0SX6uy@Ur1vGTwGpdEk5ucz99dxuLp8HZPOn1PvWA9scEjqyk8@waw5SmzTXItWKlB96hJGZ3/SW33Vg7VnIpCZ4eBgaJTK2K6m//@48QgxomS5ZVac@JK/Ye/54lRLWlXqnJfpExRW4k2C35D@yvRt9jv9Gp@M6HNV3kOe8KmfJfNxad@p651Ji7Xs94UYfj1NRFGKe3oWYzkSxWIpiOpsvbpa3K7G6Xd4s5rNpIVarlSgmfIl/)</kbd>.