# Clases mediante arreglos c++

Tags: c++

Debo realizar un programa el cual tenga una clase (Persona) la cual tiene de atributos el telefono y nombre, debo crear un arreglo para poder llamar a 5 personas distintas, el cual permita pedir dicha informacion requerida y luego de que la tenga, mostrarla completa.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Persona{
    int telefono;
    string nombre;

public:
    void getPersona();
};

void Persona::getPersona(){
    cout<<"Telefono: "<<telefono<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<nombre<<endl;
}

int main (){
    Persona personas[5];

    for (int i=1; i<6; i++){
       cout<<personas[i].getPersona()<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El nuevo problema que sale, es este, me gustaría entenderlo de ser posible

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `Persona::getPersona` no retorna ningun valor. Tienes que hacer la llamada a la funcion sola.

Comment: `string.h` contiene las funciones para cadenas del estilo C (`char *`). Lo que buscas está en la cabecera `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues mira, a consecuencia que percibo que estás apenas comenzando en este mundillo de la programación no puedo hacerte observaciones muy complejas; sin embargo, sí hay ciertos cambios que yo haría a tu clase Persona para una mejor implementación.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __PERSON__
#define __PERSON__
#include <iostream>

#ifndef PHONE_MAX_DIGITS
    #define PHONE_MAX_DIGITS 0x8
#endif 

typedef const char* __vcrt_string;

typedef struct person_t {
    __inline explicit person_t(const char* name, const char phone[PHONE_MAX_DIGITS]) noexcept {
        this->name = name;
        this->phone_number = phone;
    }
#if _HAS_NODISCARD
    friend __inline _NODISCARD std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, person_t const& p) noexcept {
        os << "Name: " << p.name << "\nPhone number: " << p.phone_number << '\n';
        return os;
    }

    __inline _NODISCARD __vcrt_string get_name(void) const noexcept {
        return this->name;
    }

    __inline _NODISCARD __vcrt_string get_phone_number(void) const noexcept {
        return this->phone_number;
    }
#endif
private:
    __vcrt_string name;
    __vcrt_string phone_number;
} person_t;

#endif
```

Puntos modificados: 
*No es necesario utilizar un objeto string, ya que, el tipo std::string o cualquier objeto que pretenda cumplir con el rol de la representación de una cadena de caracteres alfanuméricos, fueron hechos para implementar un principio de arquitectura de software llamado: decoradores de covariancia. Tu caso no es tan complejo como para implementar este tipo de entidades tan sofisticadas. Por tanto, te recomiendo darle un alias a un puntero constante de tipo char para almacenar tu cadena de forma nativa y con memoria dinámica (esto hará la cadena persistente y sus caracteres no serán perdidos aún cuando traslades datos de una función a otra, aplica también con objetos). 
* Por buena práctica de programación y, al tomar en cuenta que estás trabajando con C++ y no C puro, te recomiendo implementar en tu clase un constructor explícito. Los constructores explícitos son aquellos que se declaran a través del operador **new** y, usualmente, reciben una serie de datos cuyo fin es inicializar los atributos privados del objeto en cuestión. 
*Por ejemplo: 
`entity_t *entity = new entity_t(); //Constructor explicito.`

* Posterior a esto, debes estructurar tus respectivos getters, que son métodos de acceso para poder verificar los valores de tus atributos encapsulados (práctica estándar pero no necesaria). 
* Finalmente, una forma más elegante de imprimir los datos dentro de tus atributos con un formato de tipo string, es a través de la sobrecarga del operador <<. El modificador friend significa que esta sobrecarga no estará acoplado como una función miembro del objeto en sí mismo; por eso, te darás cuenta que debes pasar a tu objeto como una referencia inmutable.
* Último punto, el error en tu vector es porque el ciclo for lo has inicializado de manera errónea y tratas de acceder a una localización de memoria que no existe. 
`for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++) {...}`

Tu archivo quedaria asi:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.h"

int main(void) {
    person_t* p = new person_t("Michael", "12345678");
    std::cout << *p; //recuerda desreferenciar tu objeto
                    //para obtener acceso a la sobrecarga de operadores.
}
```

Comment: Cualquier duda puedes preguntarmela.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de corazón, estaré analizando el codigo que me mandaste y lo comentarios y cualquier cosita te pregunto! :)

Comment: Los constructores explícitos aplican para variables en el stack también. Que sea explícito no significa que puedas usarlo solo con `new`. De hecho, `new` implica manejo de memoria dinámica que debes liberar. Aunque C++ no es el mejor lenguaje para iniciarse en la programación, sería mejor que dominara bien los conocimientos que ya tiene y cuando esté listo aprenda todo lo referido a memoria.

Comment: Me parece bien. La idea era corregir el error y no confundir al que está aprendiendo.

Answer (score 1):

Mis observaciones son:

- El operador **<<** de `cout` espera un valor. La función `getPersona()` no devuelve ninguno.

Escribe simplemente `personas[i].getPersona();` y problema solucionado.

- En C++ las posiciones de los arreglos comienzan por 0.

El arreglo tiene 5 elementos y el for pasa por los números del 1 al 5 inclusive.

Esto significa que en la última iteración intentará acceder al elemento en la posición 5 (el sexto).

Las únicas posiciones posibles para los arreglos están entre 0 y N-1 siendo N la cantidad de elementos. Para este serían 0, 1, 2, 3 y 4.

- `std::endl` inserta el carácter de salto de línea al stream y lo "limpia".

No es un error pero es importante saberlo, ya que su uso reiterado puede provocar una disminución significativa del rendimiento de tu programa.

Más información en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/169744) y en [este sitio recomendable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl).

- `string.h` contiene funciones que funcionan con cadenas de texto del estilo de C (`char *`).

Posiblemente hayas querido incluir la cabecera `string`.

Comment: Agradezco muchisimo los comentarios, hice lo que me comentaste de quitarle el cout. El programa ya me ejecuta, pero cuando termine de poner los 5 telefonos y los 5 nombres, me sale que el programa ha dejado de funcionar :(

Comment: Ya edite la publicacion con el nuevo error, si lo puedes ver te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Que haya dejado de funcionar no brinda mucha información. Si puedes debugearlo y averiguar en qué punto sucede podríamos ayudarte mejor.