# Validar que solo se ingresen números y que sean en un rango en C++

Tags: c++, bucles, validación

El problema en si es que al momento de que el usuario ingresa un dato `int` válido pero al final le añade una letra se termina ciclando el programa y no se como evitar que eso pase.

```
struct {
    int hora;
}cita[100];

int i;

int main(){

    cout << "Ingrese horario de la cita:" << endl;
    cin >> cita[i].hora;
    cout << endl;
    while (cin.fail() == true) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10, '\n');
        cout << "Ingrese solo numeros" << endl;
        cin >> cita[i].precio;
    }
    if ((cita[i].hora > 8 && cita[i].hora < 21) && (cin.fail() == true)) {
    }
    else {
        error = 1;
        while (error != 0) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(10, '\n');
            cout << "Horario invalido, ingresarlo de nuevo" << endl;
            cin >> cita[i].hora;
            if (cin.fail() == false && cita[i].hora > 8 && (cita[i].hora < 21 )) {
                error = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: como ejecutas tu código? tienes muchos errores en declaración de variables.

Comment: Es solo una parte del codigo agregue la declaracion desde aqui porque el codigo base es muy grande en realidad solo me interesa saber de que manera puedo hacer que el if no se contradiga al momento de ingresar un un numero valido dentro del rango y consiguiente un tipo de valor no valido (letras, etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La lógica del primer `while` está bien. El segundo debería ser similar. Pero hazlo más fácil.

Mueve el código para pedir un número a su propia función:

```
int pedirNumero(){
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    while (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();

        cin.ignore(10, '\n');
        cout << "Ingrese solo numeros\n";
  
        cin >> n;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Ahora cuando quieras pedir una hora, usa la función que acabas de crear para obtener el número y mediante un while lo vuelves a pedir si no cumple el requisito:

```
int main(){
    
    cout << "Ingrese horario de la cita:\n";
    int hora = pedirNumero();

    while (!(hora > 8 && hora < 21)) {
        cout << "Horario invalido, ingresalo de nuevo\n";
        hora = pedirNumero();
    }
    cout << "Horario: " << hora;
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##bVBBbsIwELz7FVsqQSJRIJwqCDm3l76Ai@VsE1fOOnVseii8PbXjUNIKHyzveHZndkTbPlVC9P2jJKFciZBL3VmDvCmY6yRVQLzBruUCobPlnjFJFlospXlzDRqdpN8M/AkwwQE2@6EUkqAogMZKOwt5DkilishXLRVC4mmrdy5VkqYQ54zNK6GQmyT1glNUVqQNJtlmCYsjLdL97XeUmL1SZbDzbrXSQIPH7kizwJyOmri7DLdB6wwF7BKXbLik63bsrkStDTdSg49NcT/U8t2oFPMI/z6SP2mNC63XgJ9OnrhCsggcHpKBXcAzzOexM4dtlk7TiujBU87nSCkOgTON7urxZfQmyWvIUi/9K7jmavBLDk/612w4983e8vk/eQezUIY2H1nf1yz7YBnLtuwH).

---

Algunas observaciones:

- `cin.fail()` devuelve un booleano. Es redundante compararlo con `true`.
- Comparar un booleano con `false` tiene un poco más de sentido, pero puedes reducir `cin.fail() == false` negando el booleano, así: `!cin.fail()`.
- [`endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) llama a [`flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush), lo que puede tener un fuerte impacto en el programa. Considera usar `'\n'` o `"\n"` si lo usas seguido y el rendimiento es importante. [Más información](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/169744).

Comment: Muchas Gracias me aclaraste todo el problema