# el programa se detiene en la 10ma vuelta de un for. c++

Tags: c++

Sucede que el programa que tengo se detiene.

Se supone que debe leer:

- Nombre
- Cédula
- 5 lanzamientos
- Lanzamiento mayor
- Promedio de lanzamientos

Todo eso en un **array/vector**, eh abierto un for que recorre a los **10** atletas, el for hace **9** ciclos, en el **10mo** lee el nombre y cédula del atleta numero **10** y justo despues de "leer" el primer lanzamiento el programa deja de funcionar.

> "Proyecto.exe ha dejado de funcionar"

(esos lanzamientos están dentro de una matriz, por lo tanto uso un `for` para ahorrar lineas de código)

Todo eso sucedió luego que de cambiara todos los valores iniciales de cada `for` de **0** a **1**

> ```
> for (i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)  ------>>   for (i=1 ; i<11 ; i++)
> ```

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct atleta {
        char n[30];
        float lm,l[5],prom,pr;
        int ced,acc;
    };
    struct atleta at[10]; //Esta vaina es la estructura //

    int m,i,j,k,f1,f2,c1,c2,f3,c3,f4,c4,q,w,t,e;
    float lm2;
    int op;
    char resp='s';

    while (resp=='s' || resp=='S')
    {
    //menu <<abre//
    cout<<endl<<"Bienvenido al programa, escoga una de las siguientes opciones para continuar";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"ingresar datos de los atletas (recomendado)= 1";
    cout<<endl<<"Modificar los datos de un atleta= 2";
    cout<<endl<<"Mostrar un listado de todos los atletas= 3";
    cout<<endl<<"Mostar los datos de un atleta segun su cedula= 4";
    cout<<endl<<"Mostar los datos del ganador= 5";
    cout<<endl<<"Atletas cuyo promedio es supera los 70 metros=; 6";
    cout<<endl<<"Salir= 7";
    for (k=1;k<2;k++)
    {
        op=0;
        cout<<endl<<endl<<"Indique su opcion: ";    cin>>op;
        if(op<=0)
        {
            //system ("cls");
            cout<<endl<<"Indique una opcion valida1";
            k--;

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    //menu <<cierra//

    switch (op) 
    {
    case 1:
        system ("cls");
        for(i=1;i<11;i++) //leer datos de los 10 atletas <<abre// este es el original
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Indique el nombre del atleta Nº"<<i<<": ";
            fflush(stdin);
            gets (at[i].n);

            for (j=1;j<2;j++) //leer y validar la cedula <<abre//
            {
                cout<<endl<<"Indique la cedula del atleta: ";
                cin>>at[i].ced;
                if (at[i].ced>0 && at[i].ced<=99999999)
                {
                    //cout<<endl<<"Cedula Valida";
                }   
                else
                {
                cout<<endl<<"Ingrese una cedula valida";
                j--;
                }
            } //leer y validar la cedula <<cierra//

            cout<<endl<<"A continuacion indique los 5 lanzamientos del atleta";
            cout<<endl;
            at[i].acc=0;
            for (c1=1;c1<6;c1++) //leer y validar los 5 lanzamientos <<abre//
            {
                cout<<endl<<"ingrese el lanzamiento numero "<<c1<<": "; 
                cin>>at[i].l[c1]; //el for principal se ejecuta 10 veces a la 10ma vez el exe deja de funcionar justo aqui

                if (at[i].l[c1]<0)
                    c1--;
                else
                {

                }
                at[i].acc=at[i].acc+at[i].l[c1]; //promedio de lanzamientos del atleta de turno <<abre//

            } //leer y validar los 5 lanzamientos <<cierra//
            cout<<at[i].acc<<endl;
            at[i].prom=(at[i].acc)/5;       //promedio de lanzamientos del atleta de turno <<cierra//
            cout<<at[i].prom<<endl;
            //calcular el lanzamiento mayor del atleta <<abre//
            at[i].lm=0;

                for (c2=1;c2<6;c2++)
            {
                    if (at[i].l[c2]>at[i].lm)
                        at[i].lm=at[i].l[c2];
                    else
                        at[i].lm=at[i].lm;
            } //calcular el lanzamiento mayor del altleta <<cierra//

        } //ingresar los datos de los 10 atletas <<cierra//
        break;
    case 2: //modificar los datos de un atleta
        cout<<endl<<"indique el numero del altleta a modificar";
        cin>>m;
        for (e=1;e<2;e++)
        {
            if (m<0 && m>10)
            {
                cout<<endl<<"indique un numero valido";
                e--;
            }
            else{}
        }
        cout<<endl<<"indique el nombre";
        cin>>at[m].n;
        cout<<endl<<"indique la cedula";
        cin>>at[m].ced;
        for (t=1;t<2;t++)
        {
            if (at[t].ced>0 && at[t].ced<=99999999)
            {}  
            else
            {
                cout<<endl<<"Ingrese una cedula valida";
                t--;
            }
        };
        for (f1=1;f1<6;f1++)
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Indique el lanzamiento Nº"<<f1<<" :";
            cin>>at[m].l[f1];

            if(at[m].l[f1]<0)
            {
                cout<<endl<<"Indique una cantidad valida";
                f1--;
            }
            else {}
        }
        break;
    case 3: //mostrar los datos de todos los atletas
        system ("cls");
        cout<<endl<<"N"<<"==Ced"<<"==L1"<<"==L2"<<"==L3"<<"==L4"<<"==L5"<<"==LM"<<"==Prom"<<endl;
        for (f4=1;f4<11;f4++)
        {
            cout<<at[f4].n<<"=="<<at[f4].ced;
            for (c4=1;c4<6;c4++)
            {
                cout<<"=="<<at[f4].l[c4];
            }
            cout<<"=="<<at[f4].lm<<"=="<<at[f4].prom<<endl;
        }
        break;
    case 4: //datos de un atleta segun su cedula (utilizando una funcion)
        system ("cls");

        break;
    case 5: //atleta ganador y sus datos
        system ("cls");
        lm2=0;
        for (f3=1;f3<11;f3++)
        {
            if (at[f3].lm>lm2)
                lm2=at[f3].lm;
            else
                lm2=lm2; //lanzamiento mayor calculado//
        }
        for(f2=1;f2<11;f2++)
        {
            if(lm2==at[f2].lm)
            {
                cout<<endl<<"Atleta ganador";
                cout<<at[f2].n<<"="<<at[f2].ced;
                for (c3=1;c3<6;c3++)
                {
                    cout<<"="<<at[f2].l[c3];
                }
                cout<<"="<<at[f2].lm;
                cout<<"="<<at[f2].prom;
            }
            else {}
        }
        break;
    case 6: //atletas con un promedio mayor a 70
        system ("cls");
        for(q=1;q<11;q++)
        {
            at[q].pr=0;
            if(at[q].prom>70)
            {
                at[q].pr=at[q].prom;
            }
            else{}
        }
        for (w=1;w<11;w++)
        {
            if(at[w].pr>70)
            {
                cout<<at[w].n<<"="<<at[w].ced;
                for (c4=1;c4<6;c4++)
                {
                    cout<<"="<<at[w].l[c4];
                }
                cout<<"="<<at[w].lm;
                cout<<"="<<at[w].prom<<endl;
            }
            else{}
        }
        break; 
    case 7: //salir
        system ("cls");
        cout<<endl;
        break;
    default:
        system ("cls");
        cout<<endl<<"Indique una opcion valida"<<endl;
    } //switch case <<cierra//
    cout<<endl<<"para volver al menu presione 's', para salir del programa presione cualquier otra tecla"; cin>>resp;
    system ("cls");
    } //while <<cierra//
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si depuras tu programa paso por paso el problema te resultaría evidente. Te aconsejo hacerlo como ejercicio didáctico. Mientras tanto te explico el problema:

#### Arreglos.

- Los arreglos son un espacio de memoria que almacena objetos de un mismo tipo. Se definen de esta manera: `tipo nombre[tamaño]`, tú tienes un arreglo de tipo `atleta` declarado así:

  ```
  atleta at[10];
  ```
- Los arreglos en C++ se indexan desde `0`, así que `at[0]` corresponde a la primera posición, `at[1]` a la segunda, `at[2]` a la tercera, y así sucesivamente.
- Los arreglos en C++ se almacenan en memoria contigua, esto implica que entre el inicio de `at[0]` y el inicio de `at[1]` habrá una cantidad de bits equivalente a `sizeof(atleta)` ya que `atleta` es el tipo de los datos almacenados en el arreglo `at`.
- C++ no realiza comprobación de límites den los arreglos, por ello es posible acceder a elementos que no se corresponden con los que gestiona el arreglo.
- Aunque en C++ es posible acceder a elementos fuera de los límites del arreglo, hacerlo puede provocar que el programa lance errores en tiempo de ejecución.

#### Tu arreglo.

Tienes un arreglo de 10 `atleta`:

```
atleta at[10];
```

Que en memoria tendrá un aspecto parecido a esto:
[image]

Como puedes ver, tienes una variable llamada `at` que apunta al principio de 10 elementos contiguos (cuentalos, son exáctamente 10 aunque empiecen en 0 y acaben en 9).

#### Tu código.

> Todo eso sucedió luego que de cambiara todos los valores iniciales de cada `for` de **0** a **1**
>
> > ```
> > for (i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)  ------>>   for (i=1 ; i<11 ; i++)
> > ```

Originalmente recorrías el arreglo de la posición `0` a la posición `9` (ya que el valor 10 incumple la condición `<10`) y como esas son exactamente las posiciones de las que dispone tu arreglo `at` todo funcionaba correctamente.

Con el nuevo cambio recorres el arreglo de la posición `1` (que es la **segunda** posición del arreglo) a la posición `10` (que no existe ya que las posiciones llegan hasta `9`).

Al intentar trabajar con la posición `10` (que no está asignada al arreglo `at`) provoca que el programa falle en tiempo de ejecución.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Tienes faltas de ortografía.
- En C++ la palabra clave `struct` no forma parte del tipo, así pues no es necesaria para definir variables de tipo `struct`:

  ```
     /*struct*/ atleta at[10];
  // ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- innecesario!
  ```
- Las cabeceras de C adaptadas a C++ carecen de extensión y tienen el prefijo "*c*", así que `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` y `<math.h>` serían `<cstdio>`, `<cstdlib>` y `<cmath>` (consulta [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48268/librerias-de-c-y-c) para más detalles).
- No necesitas las cabeceras de C que estás incluyendo, aunque las hubieras incluido bien (que no ha sido el caso, ver punto anterior).

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono. muy útil toda la información que me diste.

Answer (score 5):

> Todo eso sucedió luego que de cambiara todos los valores iniciales de cada for de 0 a 1

Los índices empiezan **siempre** en 0... ¿Por qué empeñarse entonces en reinventar la rueda y hacer que empiecen en 1?

Si haces ese cambio tienes que cambiar **todos** los accesos al vector:

```
at[i]   // MAL!!!!!
at[i-1] // BIEN
```

Si no haces esto suceden dos cosas:

1. En la primera iteración (`i==1`), estás accediendo directamente al **segundo** elemento, luego estarás ignorando el primer elmento **siempre**. Esto no causa errores de ejecución pero no es un comportamiento deseado.
2. En la última iteración (`i==10`), estarás accediendo a un elemento que **no pertenece** al vector. Lo que sucede aquí es que accedes a memoria que no pertenece a tu vector... si la memoria a la que accedes pertenece a tu programa pisarás memoria y el programa se volverá errático... si la memoria no te pertenece el Sistema Operativo matará tu proceso para evitar que corrompas memoria de otros procesos.

Así pues, te sugiero que te hagas un favor y te acostumbres a recorrer los vectores en el rango (0..n-1) en vez de en el rango (1..n). Conseguirás que tu código esa compatible con el del 100% de los programadores que saben hacer las cosas.

Y ya hablando que hablamos de tu código:

**¿¿??**

Este código no tiene ningún sentido:

```
for (k=1;k<2;k++)
{
    op=0;
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"Indique su opcion: ";    cin>>op;
    if(op<=0)
    {
        //system ("cls");
        cout<<endl<<"Indique una opcion valida1";
        k--;

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Tu idea es iterar hasta que el usuario introduzca una opción válida... para eso existe `while` cuya traducción *mientras* es más adecuada a este contexto. En beneficio de tu propia salud, procura que el código sea lo más legible posible:

```
do
{
  cout<<endl<<endl<<"Indique su opcion: ";
  cin>>op;
  if(op<=0)
    cout<<endl<<"Indique una opcion valida\n";
} while( op <= 0 );
```

**No mezcles buffers**

En tu programa estás usando las librerías `iostream` y `stdio.h`. La primera es propia de C++ y la segunda una reminiscencia para mantener cierta compatibilidad con C... pero **no deberías usarla**.

Uno de los motivos que esgrimen muchos *gurús* que está aprendiendo para justificar que C es mucho más rápido que C++ es que la lectura de datos en C++ es lentísima... bien esto es así porque, justamente por mantener `stdio.h`, se fuerza a que ambos sistemas estén sincronizados... lo que crea un sobreesfuerzo en la capa de C++... sin embargo lo que estos *gurús* no saben es que esta sincronización se puede deshabilitar... permitiendo que las lecturas en C++ sean más rápidas que las de C.

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); // Para desincronizar los streams
```

Las lecturas con `iostream` son mucho más seguras porque tienen la ventaja de estar tipadas... cosa que no sucede con las funciones propias de C. Esta característica hace que el compilador te pueda avisar ante determinadas aberraciones o despistes... las funciones de C no mostrarán avisos y el error te lo encontrarás al ejecutar la aplicación

Ahora bien, como existe esta opción y alguien la puede activar en cualquier momento, no parece buena idea basar el buen hacer de tu programa en la asunción de que esto no existe o no se va a hacer nunca.

Para leer una línea desde la consola plantéate algo así:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

En vez de

```
gets (at[i].n);
```

Así mismo, considera usar `std::string` en vez de `char[]`.

**fflush no es para streams de entrada**

`fflush` está pensado para ejecutarse en dispositivos de salida y así se indica en la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/):

> In all other cases, the behavior depends on the specific library implementation. In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (**but this is not portable expected behavior**).

Es decir:

> En el resto de casos, el comportamiento dependerá de la implementación de la librería. En algunas implementaciones, llamar a `fflush` para un *stream* de lectura provoca el vaciado del mismo (pero no es un comportamiento portable).

Así pues, evita esto:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Para limpiar el buffer de entrada en C++ usa esto:

```
#include <limits>

std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
```

Esta función elimina todos hasta que se encuentre un salto de línea ('\n'), que también se eliminará... o se vacíe completamente el buffer de entrada.

Y bueno, habría más cosas pero lo dejamos para otro día que si no no va a haber quien se lea esta respuesta.

Comment: yo la leo entera ajajaj, gracias me sirvió mucho tu información.

Comment: Otra cosa, podrias explicarme un poco mejor lo del cin ignore ?

Comment: @KristhianQuintero echa un vistazo a este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21817/para-que-sirve-y-como-se-limpia-el-buffer)

Answer (score 0):

Cundo tienes un menú de opciones lo más recomendable es usar un do { menú de opciones }while( condición aquí );

Y si antes te funcionaba porque no lo dejaste como estaba ¿?, te recomiendo que valides errores con try catch si es posible en c porque por lo general yo solo sé de Java.Recuerda que cuando algo funciona no lo toques. y es posible que  tu problema se base en que como son 10 ,tú empiezas de 1 y no de 0 a 10, tal vez tengas que poner for(int i=1,i<=10;i++){ tus códigos aquí }
Etc.. prueba así el problema entre contadores y acumuladores siempre suele ser la inicialización.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de la linea que dice `cout<<endl<<"A continuacion indique los 5 lanzamientos del atleta";`, haces un for donde c1 va desde 1 hasta 5, pero estas intentando recorrer el arreglo `l` el cual tiene 5 elementos, pero los elementos de un arreglo no comienzan a enumerarse desde 1 sino desde cero. Debes ser cuidadoso con esas cosas. Parece que las excepciones que eso causa por intentar acceder a un registro de la RAM invalido es lo que detiene tu programa.

Comment: sucede que una opcion del menu es: **"Modificar los datos de un atleta"**, entonces cuando pongo **cout<<endl<<"indique el numero del altleta a modificar";** para seleccionar el atleta 1 deberia ingresar 0, pense que era mas comodo pero solo me dio problemas

Comment: @KristhianQuintero: No te preocupes, solamente tienes que agregarle un elemento mas al arreglo y listoo